# Easy JQuery question: populate a select box with an object rather than html text?

Tags: jquery, dom

In ASP C#, you can create a select (ListBox) then populate it with items (ListItem): ListBox1.Items.Add( new ListItem("Display name", "value"));  This has an Add method that takes a ListItem option object.

**Is there something similar in JQuery where you can add JavaScript objects to JQuery selected DOM objects without using ad hoc html text?**

Dumb question but I wanted to make sure I wasn't completely missing something to add JavaScript variables that are DOM elements to JQuery selected items.

Comment: 'add JavaScript variables that are DOM elements'. What do you mean by this? Do you want to add DOM elements like div to a select box?

Comment: The question is not so clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.appendChild(document.createTextNode('test'));
$('select').append(opt);
```

Works for me (I tested in IE 6, Firefox 3 and Safari 4).